# dried up OR drying up

Tags: grammar

**"Up came the sun, and dried up all the rain."**, this is a children song lyric. I am wondering if we change the lyric to **"Up came the sun, drying up all the rain."**, will it still be the same as what it was meant in the beginning? Or will it be a different meaning?

Answer (score 1):

If the itsy-bitsy spider tried to climb up the water spout again before it wasn't *actually* dry, but only in the process of drying, it might slip and fall. :)

In short, **dried** means that it's no longer wet. Meanwhile, **drying** means that it's still at least slightly wet.

In practice, **drying up all the rain** might be assumed to mean that the sun finished its task—but it doesn't *have* to mean that.

---

**Update**: To address some comments about what I mean when I say *it doesn't* ***have*** *to mean that*.

The same words can be interpreted in two different ways.

> Up came the sun, drying up all the rain. And . . .

**Interpretation 1**: The sun came up and began the process of drying up the rain. The process was ongoing. The rain was *still* being dried up when what is described in the next sentence takes place. (The spider climbed up a still-wet spout.)

**Interpretation 2**:The sun came up and both began and finished the process of drying up the rain. The rain is *finished* being dried when what is described in the next second takes place. (The spider climbed up a now-dry spout.)

Since both *meanings* can be inferred from *exactly the same words*, there is no way of knowing for certain which of those two things actually happened.

It may be one of those things but it may also be the other.

If you want to *unambiguously* relay the fact that the spout is actually dry at the time that the spider climbs up it again, then use the word **dried** not **drying**.

Comment: I still don't get it clearly. So  "Up came the sun, drying up all the rain." means the sun hasn't dried up the rain yet, instead, it's in the process of drying the rain up?

Comment: No, I just want to interpret it in the case of what it is in the first place, not in a normal sentence form. I don't understand your line "drying up all the rain might be assumed to mean that the sun finished its task". Do you mean "Up came the sun, drying up all the rain." emphasizes what the sun did to the rain?

Comment: How about the line "—but it doesn't have to mean that.", what does it mean?

Comment: @RelativeClausesvsParticiple I have moved my comments into an update to the answer itself in an attempt to clarify.

Comment: I have a question about interpretation 2. Did the sun simultaneously begin and finish the process of drying up the rain?

Comment: @RelativeClausesvsParticiple In *neither* interpretation will that process have taken place instantaneously. It always takes some amount of time. In the sample past verb conjugation, however, any event in question is known to have completed.

Comment: So it's no way the sun could begin and finish the process of drying up the rain at the same time?

Comment: @RelativeClausesvsParticiple I don't see how that could ever be possible.

Comment: So the interpretation 2 means the same as the original one"Up came the sun, and dried up all the rain."?

Comment: @RelativeClausesvsParticiple Yes, that's right.